# claim the insurance to cover vs claim the cost covered by insurance

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Which of the next sentences are more natural/rightful:

> 1. I am writing to claim the insurance to cover the cost of damaged car...
> 2. I am writing to claim the cost of damaged car covered by insurance...
> 3. something even more natural :)

The general meaning, car was damaged in accident and I want insurance company cover the cost.

Thanks.

Comment: why 'write' then? I want to 'claim'...!

Answer (score 2):

I would use "file a claim" in such situation.

> I am writing to **file an insurance claim** for the cost of vehicle repairs.
>   I am writing to **file an insurance claim** for the cost of repairing my damaged vehicle.

I used "vehicle repairs" because that is what the insurance would pay for.